# Yii set model attributes and save

Tags: php, database, yii

I want to track changes in my table and save it in another table. For example, if someone edits my 'text' table, i save it in 'textchanges' table. My textchanges has 4 columns, id, textid(foreign key), old text, change date. What im trying to do, in my text controller near action update i create new textchange model and set attributes, but its not working.

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);

        if (isset($_POST['Text'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['Text'];

            $textChange = new TextsChanges();
            $textChange->setAttributes(array('TextId' => $model->text_id, 'TextBefore' => $model->text_text, 'ChangeDate' => new DateTime()));

            if ($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->text_id));
                $textChange->save();
        }

        $this->render('update', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign old values before assigned to model, like below.

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);

        if (isset($_POST['Text'])) {
            $textChange = new TextsChanges();
            $textChange->setAttributes(array('TextId' => $model->text_id, 'TextBefore' => $model->text_text, 'ChangeDate' => new DateTime()));

            $model->attributes = $_POST['Text'];

            if ($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->text_id));
                $textChange->save();
        }

        $this->render('update', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
}
```